What is the Lie derivative of Ashtekar connection and its conjugate momentum in LQG?
I am using the reference Black hole entropy from an SU(2)-invariant formulation of Type I isolated horizons for this question. I am trying to understand the two equations (30) that give the variation of Ashtekar connection $A_+$ and its conjugate momenta $\Sigma^+$ in the self-dual Platini action under diffeomorphisms induced by $\alpha : \Delta \rightarrow \mathfrak{sl(2,\mathbb{C})}$.
The equations give
\begin{align}
\delta_\alpha \Sigma^+ = [\alpha,\Sigma^+], \quad \delta_\alpha A_+ = -d_{A_+}\alpha.
\end{align}
I know that the Lie derivative between two vector fields is calculated by the Lie commutator but I do not understand why is it that for conjugate momenta we get a commutator and for the connection one form we get $\delta_\alpha A_+ = -d_{A_+}\alpha$.
Thanks in advance for any help.

This has nothing to do specifically with Ashtrkar variables, it’s only a general rule of how the Lie derivative acts on tensors.

@Prof.Legolasov is there a reference that I can learn similar calculations from it with similar examples?

Just look up the definition of Lie derivative acting on tensors of various types. The connection is a rank-1 covariant tensor. That definition reduces to the expression you’re wondering about.

@Prof.Legolasov I get $\mathcal{L}\alpha A=\mathcal{L}\alpha(A_{+\mu} dx^\mu)=[\alpha,A_{+\mu}]dx^\mu+A_{+\mu} \partial_\nu \alpha^\mu dx^\nu$. I do not understand how this will lead to $d_{A_+}\alpha=d\alpha+[A_\mu,\alpha]$. Sorry if this is a very stupid question.

Your first formula is wrong, the lie derivative expands into two inequivalent terms when it acts on a covariant vector field.

@Prof.Legolasov I dont understand. Is there a reference for explicit calculation?

I may write an answer later (no time now sorry), but are you even sure you’re looking at the right formula? The formula (30) from that paper is a change under a gauge transformation, in your answer $\alpha$ maps into $SL(2, \mathbb{C}))$ so clearly parameterizes a gauge transformation. The commutator is the Lie algebra bracket not the vector field bracket. The diffeomorphism formula that uses the Lie derivative seems to be equation (31) not (30).

@Prof.Legolasov I am totally confused. $\alpha$ is defined as $\alpha: \Delta \rightarrow \mathfrak{sl(2,\mathbb{C})}$. Then,  as a guage transformation the action of $\alpha$ should send $A$ to some $gAg^{-1}+gdg^{-1}$, right? But, g belongs to the group and $\alpha$ is Lie algebra valued. I really dont understand. sorry.

That’s correct, but that’s a global transformation. Now to derive the infinitesimal transformation, plug $g = 1 + \alpha + \mathcal{O}(\alpha^2)$ to get the formula with the covariant derivative.

I added an expanded answer to help with your confusion. PTAL.

Let's derive these transformation laws from the first principles.
Start with the gauge transformation.
Let's have a field $\psi(x)$ that transforms in some representation $\rho$ of the gauge group. Then we have,
$$ \psi(x) \mapsto \psi'(x) = \rho(g(x)) \psi(x), $$
parameterized by the group-valued map $g(x)$.
There's a mapping between (at least the neighborhood of the identity element in) the group and the algebra, it's called the exponential map.
Probably the best way to see it is to consider the universal enveloping algebra (UEA) which contains both the Lie algebra and the Lie group.
Working in the UEA, we can write an equation
$$ g(x) = 1 + \varepsilon \alpha(x) + \mathcal{O}(\varepsilon^2), $$
which relates the finite gauge transformation parameterized by $g(x)$ and the infinitesimal transformation parameterised by $\alpha(x)$ and the infinitesimal parameter $\varepsilon$.
The infinitesimal transformation law for $\psi(x)$ is then,
$$ \psi(x) \mapsto \left(1 + \varepsilon \rho(\alpha(x)) \right) \psi(x), $$
$$ \frac{\delta \psi(x)}{\delta \varepsilon} = \rho(\alpha(x)) \psi(x). $$
Now note that the gradient of $\psi$ doesn't transform linearly:
$$ d \psi \mapsto \rho(g) d \psi + d \rho(g) \cdot \psi. $$
To compensate, we introduce the covariant derivative $D \psi = d \psi + \rho(A) \psi$. By construction,
$$ D \psi \mapsto \rho(g) D \psi. $$
As an exercise I will leave deriving the transformation law for $A$ from here.
You already posted it in your comments, so I am sure you're familiar with it:
$$ A \mapsto g A g^{-1} + g dg^{-1}. $$
Note that we can write an equation without $\rho$ here, because the above reasoning is valid for any representation $\rho$. This equation is valid in the UEA, so it's not a problem that we have Lie group and algebra elements in the same equation.
Now to derive the infinitesimal form:
$$ g(x) = 1 + \varepsilon \alpha(x) + \mathcal{O}(\varepsilon^2), $$
$$ A \mapsto \left( 1 + \varepsilon \alpha \right) A \left( 1 - \varepsilon \alpha \right) + \left( 1 + \varepsilon \alpha \right) d \left( - \varepsilon \alpha \right) + \mathcal{O}(\varepsilon^2) = $$
$$ A - \varepsilon [A, \alpha] - \varepsilon d \alpha + \mathcal{O}(\varepsilon^2). $$
$$ \frac{\delta A}{\delta \varepsilon} = - d \alpha - [A, \alpha] = - d \alpha - \rho_{\text{adjoint}}(A) \alpha = - D_A \alpha. $$
Here $D_A \alpha$ is the covariant derivative taken in the adjoint representation.
That's your formula (30) from your post.

Thank you so much. I got my answer.
